# How to hide a css class in a specific slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap slider with a burger menu at the top, and i want to show it in every slide except for the first one. Do i have to use this burger class in every slide except for the first one? Or there is simpler way to do that? Any kind of help would be much appreciated

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="navigation">
     <div class="burger_deluxe">
        <span class="burger_global top_bun"></span>
        <span class="burger_global patty"></span>
        <span class="burger_global bottom_bun"></span>
     </div>
  </div>


   <div class="carousel-item first_slide">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item second_slide">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item third_slide">
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 400;
  position: absolute;
}
  .burger_deluxe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 34px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.burger_deluxe .burger_global {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  width: 100%;
}
.burger_deluxe .burger_global.top_bun {
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease, border 500ms ease;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.burger_deluxe .burger_global.patty {
  top: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}
.burger_deluxe .burger_global.bottom_bun {
  top: 24px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease, border 500ms ease;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.burger_deluxe.open span {
  border-color: white;
}
.burger_deluxe.open .top_bun {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.burger_deluxe.open .patty {
  opacity: 0;
}
.burger_deluxe.open .bottom_bun {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce an issue?

Comment: There are not many details. If the problem only occurs at first slide (I assume this is full-width slide) you may lack some kind of  `active` / `active-slide`  class for it. I can't see any of your slides having that type of indicator. Usually, libraries add this kind of classes in JS after slide changes. Check if this is the case. If your lib adds any class to the second slide if it changes and copy that class to your first slide in HTML file.

Comment: Hi, actually my first slide has active class. What i want to do is, hide this navigation class for the first slide, so that my first slide don't show any burger menu.